# Official site to follow Warren Buffet's Berkshire Hathaway change in investment holdings?

Tags: stocks, investing, portfolio

Recently, from a public web site unofficial source, I found out that Warren Buffet's company Berkshire Hathaway is increasing its stake in Wells Fargo.

Is there a web site where I can get official information to keep track of any change in holdings owned by Berkshire Hathaway?

Comment: hmm wonder if this will become known as buffets bailout.  First major purchace of WFC now BOA.  Wonder if Chase is next.

Comment: Unofficial information: CNBC's [Berkshire Hathaway Portfolio Tracker](https://www.cnbc.com/berkshire-hathaway-portfolio/). For official information, look into Berkshire Hathaway's Form 13F filings available on SEC EDGAR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for this [Warren Buffets Stock Portfolio](http://warren-buffett-portfolio.com/)?

Or [Berkshire Hathaway Portfolio](http://www.tickerspy.com/pro/Warren-Buffett---Berkshire-Hathaway)

WFC is near the bottom of the BH portfolio but it seems to be a rather large investment for both.

Comment: damn, his portfolio is doing pretty good!

Answer (score 4):

The official source is the most recent Form 13F that Berkshire Hathaway, which is  filed with the Securities & Exchange Commission on a quarterly basis .  You can find it through the [SEC filing search engine](http://sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html), using BRKA as the ticker symbol. and then looking for the filings marked 13-FR or 13-FR/A (the "/A" indicates an amended filing).

As you can see by looking at the [13-F filed for the quarter ending September 30](http://sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1067983/000119312511312418/d258700d13fhra.txt)  , the document isn't pretty or necessarily easy to read, hence the popularity of sites such as those that Chad linked to. It is, though, the truly official source from which websites tracking the Berkshire Hathaway portfolio derive their information.